# Javascript function not finding ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to code something in Javascript that will call a function on PageLoad that will find the height of a Calender_Control. If the height is equal to 398px then set the height of a text area to have 4 rows, else set the rows to 6.

This is what I have tried so far and it isn't finding the ID.

```
        function changeHeight() {
        var height = document.getElementById("#calender_control");
        if (height == 398) {
            document.getElementById("#calender_control").rows = "4";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("#calender_control").rows = "6";
        }
    }
```

Why isn't my piece of code working?

Comment: `document.getElementById("calender_control");` and not `document.getElementById("#calender_control");`

Comment: gEBI does not need the `#`. You've already said you're looking for an ID, so specifying the `#` is redundant. You're telling JS to look for `<foo id="#calender_control">`

Comment: Since this is tagged ASP.NET, you need to make sure you use the Client ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to do using **javascript** for selecting element by id:

```
document.getElementById("calender_control")
```

but if you want with **jquery** then:

```
$("#calender_control")
```

`$("#calender_control")` is equivalent to  `document.getElementById("calender_control")`

Comment: Thanks for that, but still my textarea isn't changing to the rows that I said for it to change to?

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` does not use a hash to denote an id.

But that's just the first problem, you're expecting to get a number from a call to `getElementById`:

```
var height = document.getElementById("#calender_control");
if (height == 398) { ...
```

But the call to `getElementById` returns an HTMLDomElement

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery.

```
function changeHeight() {
    var height = $("#calender_control").height();
    if (height == 398) {
        $("#calender_control").attr("rows", "4");
    }
    else {
        $("#calender_control").attr("rows", "6");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code...

```
 function changeHeight() {
    var height = document.getElementById("calender_control").height;
    if (height == 398) {
        document.getElementById("calender_control").rows = "4";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("calender_control").rows = "6";
    }}
```